# Write output from command line into file in vim

Tags: vim, macros, replace

I would like to insert at the end of each line the number of alphabetic characters on that line.  To do this on one line is easy.  I search using `:s/\a//gn` and get the occurrence of alphabetic characters in the command line and then `A` and space and enter the number.

My problem arises when I have so many lines that it becomes extremely tedious to do this.  I am trying to create a macro but am having difficulty getting command line output into it.  Is there a way to do this without resorting to *nix commands?  I have access to a *nix box but not all the time.

So if my file had the following content:

```
abc2d4s
jd4a5ag
jdf7fjf
abdd5ff
```

I would like the output to look like this:

```
abc2d4s 5
jd4a5ag 5
jdf7fjf 6
abdd5ff 6
```

I was thinking if there was a way to get the replace output piped into the register somehow but cannot figure out how to do it, but maybe there is a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can capture the output of the `:s///gn` command with `:redir`, but in this case, I would rather implement the counting via `substitute()` and `:help sub-replace-expression`:

```
:%s/.*/\=submatch(0) . ' ' . len(substitute(submatch(0), '\A', '', 'g'))/
```

This matches the entire line (`.*`), then removes all non-alphabetic characters (`\A`), and appends the length of the result. Note: Works only for ASCII characters (but `\a` covers only those, anyway)!

Comment: @Kent: Thanks, I guess I saved some typing by using the inverse `\A`.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do that would be to use a simple macro:

```
:%norm A <C-v><C-r>=col('.')-2<C-v><CR>
```

which should look like:

```
:%norm A ^R=col('.')-2^M
```

where we enter insert mode at the end of each line and insert a space followed by the column number of the last character.

A variant:

```
:%norm A^R=" ".len(getline('.'))^M
```

Answer (score 2):

this cmd should give you that output:

```
%s/.*/\=submatch(0).' '.(len(submatch(0))-len(substitute(submatch(0),'\a','','g')))
```